# How to de-duplicate rows while retaining the row with the highest value of another column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a big spreadsheet that I want to de-duplicate based on just one column, but with a twist.

I'm using a variation of [this script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates), here it is:

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row[7] == newData[j][7]){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Now I need the de-duplication to be more nuanced, to work such that it retains the row with the highest value in another column (column B aka 1 in this case). How could I modify my script to account for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the if statement to the following:

```
if(row[7] == newData[j][7] && row[1] < newData[j][1]){
        duplicate = true;
        break; //This will stop the loop when a duplicate is found. 
      }
```

This will set duplicate = true for any row whose value in column b is smaller than the largest value in column B for a given duplicate entry in column 8.

Hope that helps

**Edit Overlooked this Error previously**

In the below piece of code, the loop should go through data array and not newData array (newData array would be empty!)

```
for(j in newData){
      if(row[7] == newData[j][7] && row[1] < newData[j][1]){
            duplicate = true;
            break; //This will stop the loop when a duplicate is found. 
          }
    }
```

Find the modified code below:

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    // I replaced all newData to data where appropiate 
    for(j in data){
      if(row[7] == data[j][7] && row[1] < data[j][1]){
            duplicate = true;
            break; //This will stop the loop when a duplicate is found. 
          }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```